# Looking for some sort of TableViewDidDisplayNotification

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

I have a split view based app, and would like to listen for some sort of notification for when the root menu is displayed.  The reason I want to do this is because the keyboard overlaps the menu, so I would like to hide the keyboard when the menu is displayed.

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) 
                                                 name:<Some Notification Here> 
                                               object:self.view.window];
```

I already have the method to hide the keyboard, I'm just looking for the appropriate notification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can post the notification yourself from the root menu. Just subclass it and post the notification on `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear`.

The word of warning: if you are targeting iOS 5 and up you should kep in mind the `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` are deprecated in iOS6. use 
`willMoveToParentViewController` or `didMoveToParentViewController` or `-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews`

```
-(void)willMoveToParentViewController:(UIViewController *)parent{
    if (!parent)
      //post notification here


}
```

Also, you can provide nil as a notification name and listen to any possible notification, then NSLog it out, perhaps you can find a useful notification there, just make sure it is documented to futureproof your product.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationReceived:) name:nil object:nil];
```

Comment: Where do you see that those 2 functions are deprecated? I see nothing about this in the docs.

Comment: I read that it is not good practise to subclass notifications, is this true ?

Comment: I meant subclass the root menu, not a notification